# Is it possible to re-generate ECPublic key from raw private key and curve params?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

As per my understanding, in Elliptical curve cryptography, the EC PrivateKey is nothing but a bigInteger value. If you know the curve specs and you have this private BigInteger value (which I am referring as raw private key), then you can re-create PrivateKey and use it for generating the signature.

Now, my question is, if you know the raw privateKey and curve name (aka specs), can you generate the corresponding public key?

Comment: Of course: If you know the curve $E$ and base point $P\in E$, the public key is simply computed as $Q=xP$ where $x\in\mathbb N$ is the private key.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer later on after reading this
http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15307/25460

Comment: Shall we close the question as a duplicate of [the linked one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15298/23623) or do you (ua741) want a real answer (from @yyyyyyy ?)?

Comment: @yyyyyyy Can you please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480776/how-do-i-obtain-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-private-key-in-openssl is basically the same question with an answer specific to OpenSSL.